# The Closedness in the hypothesis of Tietze extension theorem is necessary

Tags: general-topology

> Consider $B=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ and $D=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> 1) Given a continuous function $f:B \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, there exist a continuous function $g:\Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $g=f$ on $B$.
>
> 2) Given a continuous function $s:D \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, there exist a continuous function $t:\Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $t=s$ on $D$.

I know 1) follows from Tietze extension theorem, since $B$ is closed and $\Bbb{R}$ is a normal space.

What about 2? Any hint must be appreciated!

Comment: Part 2 is incorrect. To disprove this, construct a function that becomes unbounded near the boundary of $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple example where 2. fails: let $s: D \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $s(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$. You cannot even continuously extend it to a single point of $B \setminus D =S^1$.

Comment: And another trivial counterexample for 1 is $f(x,y) = (x^2 +y^2-2)^{-1}$